# How to set textView alignment with Java in Android?

Tags: java, android, textview, alignment

I'm working on an app that incorporates a chat activity. I'm currently trying to make it look appealing by giving incoming and outgoing messages different colors and locations on the screen. I can't seem to figure out how to make the outgoing messages align to the right of the listview. The first part of the if statement is meant for the outgoing message. Thanks in advance!

```
package com.example.muhryn.resonatem;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;

public class ChatList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public ChatList (Activity context, List<String> values) {
        super(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
    }

    public View getView (int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView textView=new TextView(super.getContext());

        String text=super.getItem(position);

        if (text.startsWith("(")) {
            text=text.substring(text.indexOf(')')+1).trim();
            textView.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.argb(255,251,175,66));
            textView.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.argb(255, 26, 26, 26));
            textView.setTextSize(20);



        } else
            textView.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.argb(255,244,245,246));
            textView.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.argb(255, 26, 26, 26));
            textView.setTextSize(20);



        textView.setText(text);

        return textView;

    }

}
```

[How it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUxuW.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to align the text to the right side

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT)
```

Comment: The chats both still align to the left, I attached a picture to the original post to show the current situation.

Comment: Oh, I see now.  You can make a new arrayList and Listview for the outgoing messages.  Then make a custom adapter instead of using simple_list_item_1.  In that adapter's  textview.xml file, add this android:gravity="right"

Comment: check out this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763224/how-to-make-text-align-in-android-listview-from-right-to-left

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is you are using a single list view or text view. So if you give gravity all the messages would get the gravity. try using two different text views or list views. maybe that would be useful.

Check this out might be useful..

[left and right alignment rows inside Listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762473/left-and-right-alignment-rows-inside-listview)